# Align text vertically next to SVG in xsl

Tags: pdf, xslt, svg, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm trying to align a text next to an SVG image insde an XSL which then is used to create a pdf.

This is where I have both text and SVG set up:

```
<fo:block font-size="14pt" text-align="center" margin-top="2cm">
    <fo:instream-foreign-object>
        <svg:svg width="30" height="30" xml:space="preserve">
            <svg:g style="fill:none; stroke:black; stroke-width:1">
                <svg:rect x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30"/>
            </svg:g>
        </svg:svg>
    </fo:instream-foreign-object>

    Mark If Closed
</fo:block>
```

This is the output:

[image]

I want the text "Mark If Closed" to be vertically in the middle with the square SVG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the size of the square is constant, you could play with baseline-shift. Given SVG height of 30 and font-size of 14pt, a baseline-shift of about 5pt would do it.

```
            <fo:block font-size="14pt" text-align="center" background-color="silver">
            <fo:instream-foreign-object>
                <svg:svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" xml:space="preserve">
                        <svg:g style="fill:none; stroke:black; stroke-width:1">
                            <svg:rect x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30"/>
                        </svg:g>
                </svg:svg>
            </fo:instream-foreign-object><fo:inline background-color="yellow" baseline-shift="5pt">Mark If Closed</fo:inline></fo:block>
```

Yields this (color added for clarity):

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I couldn't find much information online. This made the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Let the formatter work it out...

Make the formatter do the math (assuming that `line-height` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#line-height) is '1.2'):

```
<fo:block font-size="14pt" text-align="center" margin-top="2pt"
    background-color="silver">
    <fo:instream-foreign-object baseline-shift="-((30pt - 1em * 1.2) div 2)">
        <svg:svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" xml:space="preserve">
    <svg:g style="fill:none; stroke:black; stroke-width:1">
        <svg:rect x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30" />
    </svg:g>
</svg:svg>
    </fo:instream-foreign-object>
    <fo:inline background-color="yellow">Mark If Closed</fo:inline>
</fo:block>
```

Move the box down by 50%:

```
<fo:block font-size="14pt" text-align="center" margin-top="2pt"
    background-color="silver">
    <fo:instream-foreign-object baseline-shift="-50%">
        <svg:svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" xml:space="preserve">
            <svg:g style="fill:none; stroke:black; stroke-width:1">
                <svg:rect x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30" />
            </svg:g>
        </svg:svg>
    </fo:instream-foreign-object>
    <fo:inline background-color="yellow">Mark If Closed</fo:inline>
</fo:block>
```

Use `alignment-baseline` on the `fo:instream-foreign-object` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#alignment-baseline):

```
<fo:block font-size="14pt" text-align="center" margin-top="2pt"
    background-color="silver">
    <fo:instream-foreign-object alignment-baseline="middle">
        <svg:svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" xml:space="preserve">
    <svg:g style="fill:none; stroke:black; stroke-width:1">
        <svg:rect x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30" />
    </svg:g>
</svg:svg>
    </fo:instream-foreign-object>
    <fo:inline background-color="yellow">Mark If Closed</fo:inline>
</fo:block>
```

[image: Screenshot from formatting examples]

Comment: FYI, Only the third option works if the person posting is using FOP which he set as a tag. Your examples are not using FOP for sure.